# dynamic sql query php with AND

Tags: php, sql

I have some sql code:

```
    $id = "2000";
    $model = $_GET["model"]

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT
    Left(Right(Base.inputs.Data_inf,4),3) As 'Datas',
    count(Base.Data.Data_ID) As `U_Count`
    FROM
        Base.Data
    WHERE
        Product = '$id'
        AND model in ('a','b','c')
    GROUP BY ");
```

I would like to make AND part of query to be dynamic. Something like this:

```
$m= $model;
switch ($m)
{
    case "basic":
        $m = "AND model in ('a','b','c')";
        break;

    case "upgrade":
        $m = "AND model in ('d','e','f')";
        break;

    default:
        $m = "AND model in ('a','b','c')";
}
```

I put $m in the query and it doesn't work:

```
WHERE
      Product = '$id'
      '$m'
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around $m. Also, add spaces and replace AND with the right condition:

```
$m= $model;
switch ($m)
{
    case "basic":
        $m = " AND model in ('a','b','c') ";
        break;

    case "upgrade":
        $m = " AND model in ('d','e','f') ";
        break;

    default:
        $m = " AND model in ('a','b','c') ";
}
```

And then do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT
Left(Right(Base.inputs.Data_inf,4),3) As 'Datas',
count(Base.Data.Data_ID) As `U_Count`
FROM
    Base.Data
WHERE
    Product = '$id'
    $m ");
```

Comment: you're welcome :) But you should indeed replace AND with the right condition to select any of these variants, otherwise it won't work, because one field can't be equal to all of these values at the same time. Going to edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `OR` operator instead of `AND`, or better to use `IN` statement.
Because I guess model can't at the same time be equal to `a`  and `b`, it's impossible
So part of your code should look like this:

```
$m = " AND model in ('a','b','c')";
```

**EDIT:**
You can simplify your code something like this:

```
$id = "2000";
$model = $_GET["model"]



$m= $model;
switch ($m)
{
    case "upgrade":
    $mIN = "'d','e','c'";
        break;

    case "basic":
    default:
    $mIN = "'a','b','c'";
        break;
}


$result = mysql_query("SELECT
Left(Right(Base.inputs.Data_inf,4),3) As 'Datas',
count(Base.Data.Data_ID) As `U_Count`
FROM
    Base.Data
WHERE
    Product = '$id'
    AND model in ($mIn)
GROUP BY ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your SQL as a string before passing it through. If also makes it easier to debug your query prior to running it.

```
    $querytop = "SELECT
        Left(Right(Base.inputs.Data_inf,4),3) As 'Datas',
        count(Base.Data.Data_ID) As `U_Count`
        FROM
            Base.Data
        WHERE
            Product = '$id'";

    $m= $model;
    switch ($m)
    {
        case "basic":
            $m = " AND model = 'a'
        AND model = 'b'
        AND model = 'c' ";
            break;

        case "upgrade":
            $m = " AND model = 'd'
        AND model = 'e'
        AND model = 'f' ";
            break;

        default:
            $m = " AND model = 'a'
        AND model = 'b'
        AND model = 'c' ";
    }        
    $sqlquery = $querytop . $m;
    $result = mysql_query("$sqlquery");
```